# jsoup - Would it be possible to get the parent page of a page?

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, jsoup, hierarchy

I am capturing website content using a crawler that is composed of jsoup.

Would it be possible for me to get the parent page of a certain page?

I am talking about the hierarchical structure of a website.

See image:
[Website Hierarchical Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqdGX.png)

For example, "About Company"'s parent is "Homepage". While "Mission"'s parent is "About Company".

If you would ask if how I get the links, I use these code:

***Spider Class***

```
  public void search(String url)
  {
      while(this.pagesVisited.size() < MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH)
      {
          String currentUrl = "";

          SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
          if(this.pagesToVisit.isEmpty())
          {
              currentUrl = url;
              parent = url;
              this.pagesVisited.add(url);
          }
          else
          {
              currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
          }

          System.out.println("Current URL: " + currentUrl);
          leg.crawl(currentUrl, parent, pagesVisited);
          this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
          System.out.println("Pages to Visit: " + pagesToVisit.size());
      }
      System.out.println("\n**Done** Visited " + this.pagesVisited.size() + " web page(s)");
  }

private String nextUrl()
  {
      String nextUrl;
      do
      {
          nextUrl = this.pagesToVisit.remove(0);
      } while(this.pagesVisited.contains(nextUrl));
      this.pagesVisited.add(nextUrl);
      return nextUrl;
  }
```

***Spider Leg Class***

```
public List<String> getLinks()
    {
        return this.links;
    }
```

These codes are derived from this instructions:
['Net Instructions
—
How to make a simple web crawler in Java](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-java/)

Comment: Assuming u already downloaded all the structure, its a matter of simple mapping, if you haven't downloaded the parent page, then there is no way of knowing where the source come from(unless the source has signed it)

Comment: Sorry but, what do you mean about downloading its structure? (Sorry, I'm not that knowledgeable.)